# distinction between volume and partition (terminology)

Tags: linux, windows, macos, partitioning, volume-label

What's the definition of, and distinction between, a volume and a partition?

Wikipedia notes that a partition is created before any files or directories are written to disk.  But, then, in the next breath, continues that:  "Each partition, or volume..."

While I realize that the complexity increases quickly, what is best way to distinguish between these concepts?

Comment: [What is the difference between Volume and Partition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48021590/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What's the definition of, and distinction between, a volume and a partition?

> **Partitions**
>
> Storage media (DVD's, USB sticks, HDD's, SSD's) can all be divided
>   into partitions, these partitions are identified by a partition table.
>
> The partition table is where the partition information is stored, the
>   information stored within here is basically where the partition starts
>   and where it finishes on the disc platter.
>
> **Volumes**
>
> A Volume is a logical abstraction from physical storage.  Large disks
>   can be partitioned into multiple logical volumes Volumes are divided
>   up into fixed size blocks or a cluster or blocks.
>
> We don't see the partition as this is sorted by the file system
>   controller but we see volumes as they are logical and are provided by
>   a gui with a hierarchical structure and human interface. When we
>   request to see a file it runs through a specific order to view that
>   information from within the volume on the partition:
>
> 1. Application created the file I/O request
> 2. The file system creates a block I/O request
> 3. Block I/O drive accesses the disk

Source [What is the difference between Volume and Partition?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48022168/3536342), answer by [Daniel Everitt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9152925/daniel-everitt)

**Additional notes**

A Partition is limited to a single disk.

A Disk may contain one or multiple partitions.

A Volume may span multiple disks as there are several **types** of Volume:

> Creating a Volume or Partition
>
> You can create a new volume or partition on any disk that has empty
>   space. If the disk is dynamic, a volume is created. If the disk is a
>   basic disk, a primary partition is created. If the empty space is part
>   of an extended partition, a new logical drive will be created. All of
>   them called a simple volume, but each one a different structure.
>
> ...
>
> Depending on the number of available unallocated volumes, you see one
>   or more options for the type of volume, including the following:
>
> - New Simple Volume
> - New Spanned Volume
> - New Striped Volume
> - New Mirrored Volume
> - New RAID-5 Volume

Of the above only a Simple Volume resides on a single disk. The others reside (in parts) on multiple disks (read on for more information on volume types).

Source [Partitions and Volumes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163559.aspx)

> **Types of Volumes for Dynamic Disks**
>
> When you are working with a volume on a Dynamic Disk, you can choose
>   to extend or span that volume across multiple drives, you can stripe
>   or mirror, or in server editions you can even use RAID 5. There’s also
>   not a real limit on the number of volumes you can have, although it
>   wouldn’t make sense to have a huge number of them.
>
> Here are the types of volumes you can create on a Dynamic Disk:
>
> - Simple Volume – this is a regular “partition”. If the disk type is “Basic”, this creates an actual partition.
> - Striped Volume – data is striped across multiple hard drives so that every other segment of data is staggered between the drives for
>     maximum performance. There is no redundancy.
> - Spanned Volume – data fills up on one drive and then fills up the next drive as it gets more full. Two or more drives are basically
>     taped together to make a bigger disk. There is no redundancy here
>     either.
> - Mirrored Volume – for home users, this is the only form of redundancy that you will get with software options. Read performance
>     should be faster, but write performance will possibly be slightly
>     slower, since Windows has to write to both drives for everything.
> - RAID5 Volume – only works on server editions, but it can stripe across 3 or more hard drives and include a parity stripe to prevent
>     data loss if a drive was to fail.
>
> Note: you can’t use a Dynamic Disk for a removable / portable drive.

Source [Windows Admin: Understanding Hard Drive Partitioning with Disk Management](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson4/)

---

#### Further Reading

- [hard disk - Differences between volume, partition and drive - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87300/differences-between-volume-partition-and-drive)
- [Partitions and Volumes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163559.aspx)
- [Volume (computing) - Differences between volume and partition - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_(computing)#Differences_between_volume_and_partition)

Comment: For added mind-blowing: A volume need not have a disk at all "below" it! It is only extremely customary to deal mostly with storage-backed volumes because we do not want to loose data upon power outages and/or because using RAM throughout would not be feasible

Answer (score 1):

They are used interchangeably but in a strict sense that is probably wrong. A Partition can only be a logical space defined within a larger physical space.

A Volume on the other hand can be a descriptor for both a Physical Space, example Macintosh HD, or Logical space within a Drive such as a Windows 10 partition within the Macintosh HD. When Windows is booting up in this case, it is loading the Windows 10 Volume, which again is really a partition.

Comment: partition is confined to a single disk?  volume can span disks?  volume **may** contain partitions?  (this last one seems problematic)  Or, perhaps, partition is confined to ***either*** a single disk or a single volume.

Comment: @Thufir volumes can span multiple disks, when used in raid for example. See the link [Partitions and Volumes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163559.aspx) in the further reading section of my answer.