Hidden volume vs hidden partition
I wanted to automate hiding and unhiding partitions (volumes?) for specific users.
I usually do it manually through Disk Management by removing the drive letter which causes the drive to disappear from File Explorer.
I ran the following command to hide partition Q (labeled Tic):
Set-Partition -DriveLetter Q -IsHidden $True

It disappeared from File Explorer.
Then I went back to Disk Management and reassigned it a letter (I hadn't figured out yet how to do it programmatically).
It reappeared in File Explorer.
However, diskpart still showed the volume as hidden:
DISKPART> list partition
  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    System             260 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Reserved            16 MB   261 MB
  Partition 3    Primary            234 GB   277 MB
  Partition 4    Primary            439 GB   234 GB
  Partition 5    Primary             78 GB   674 GB
  Partition 6    Primary             48 GB   849 GB
  Partition 7    Primary             19 GB   898 GB
  Partition 8    Recovery           644 MB   953 GB

DISKPART> list volume
  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C   Windows      NTFS   Partition    234 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1     Q   Tic          NTFS   Partition    439 GB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 2     R   Tac          NTFS   Partition     78 GB  Healthy
  Volume 3         Foo          NTFS   Partition     48 GB  Healthy
  Volume 4         Bar          NTFS   Partition     19 GB  Healthy
  Volume 5         SYSTEM       FAT32  Partition    260 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 6         Windows RE   NTFS   Partition    644 MB  Healthy    Hidden

Notice how volume Tic's Info field says "Hidden" despite me having reassigned it a letter in Disk Management and it (Tic) showing up in File Explorer.

Notice also how volumes Foo and Bar, both of which I hid using Disk Management (not Set-Partition), aren't listed as hidden in diskpart despite not being shown in File Explorer.
Below are PowerShell commandlet output which showed no such discrepancies (although it seems to show less information in general):
PS > Get-Partition
PartitionNumber  DriveLetter Offset                                        Size Type
---------------  ----------- ------                                        ---- ----
1                           1048576                                     260 MB System
2                           273678336                                    16 MB Reserved
3                C           290455552                                234.38 GB Basic
4                Q           251948695552                             439.45 GB Basic
5                R           723807895552                              78.12 GB Basic
6                           912551575552                              48.83 GB Basic
7                           964980375552                              19.53 GB Basic
8                           1023527616512                               644 MB Recovery

PS > Get-Volume
DriveLetter FriendlyName     FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- ------------     -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
R           Tac              NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     62.91 GB  78.12 GB
            Bar              NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     19.48 GB  19.53 GB
            Windows RE tools NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     63.11 MB    644 MB
C           Windows          NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                    119.32 GB 234.37 GB
            SYSTEM           FAT32          Fixed     Healthy      OK                    193.47 MB    256 MB
            Foo              NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     48.74 GB  48.83 GB

Why is this happening?
I've always used "volume" and "partition" interchangeably.
Am I supposed to use get-volume and set-volume or get-partition and set-partition when programmatically hiding them?

I've found a question that specifically asks the difference between Volume and Partition: https://superuser.com/questions/1340300/distinction-between-volume-and-partition-terminology Perhaps this answers part of your question, and perhaps from it you can better understand what is happening? I recommend you read that question and perhaps other resources about the difference between a volume and partition, and if you still have a question along these lines, edit this post to take that new knowledge into account.

First answer in the linked question is vague. For example, "Storage media (DVD's, USB sticks, HDD's, SSD's) can all be divided into partitions" "Large disks can be partitioned into multiple logical volumes" - I can't tell the difference. Sounds like two ways to say the same thing. The other answer literally says they're interchangeable.

Basically, a Partition is the amount of space set aside on a storage device, and a Volume is the actual file system (NTFS/FAT/etc). Windows lets you use either one in many cases, but only Partitions can be set to Hidden. Windows assigns drive letters to volumes, so a partition can be hidden and show a drive letter

@Cpt.Whale thank you, that makes more sense. Does that mean that Disk Management doesn't hide the partition when I click "Remove", even though the partition/volume stops showing up in File Explorer (see Foo and Bar)? It's just that File Explorer is incapable of showing volumes/partitions/drives without a letter? At the same time Set-Partition -IsHidden $True seems to do both at the same time?

I don't have one to test with at the moment, so I'm not sure what exactly gets set by disk management. You are correct that file explorer (and windows in general) will only show drives with a letter assigned. I believe the Hidden attribute just tells windows not to automatically assign a drive letter, like at boot or when plugged in. It makes sense to me that disk management would do both actions for you, but powershell may be two steps
